# Isometries of non-singular bilinear space over field of characteristic $\neq 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In the book of Geometric Algebra, Artin says (p. 108)

> If $V$ is a non-singular bilinear space then any isometry $T:V\rightarrow V$ has determinant $1$ or $-1$. The map 
>   $$\mbox{Isom}(V)\rightarrow \{1,-1\}, \,\,\,\,\,\,T\mapsto \det(T)$$ is a homorphism. The image of this homomorphism is $\{1,-1\}$ or just  $\{1\}$ (**in case there are no reflections or if the characteristic of k is 2**).

**Question 1.** Can there be a case of non-survectivity of above map where field is of characteristic $\neq 2$ for some non-singular space?

I mean, I want to know example (if exists) of a non-singular space with all isometries of determinant $1$ but characteristic of field is not $2$.

On the page 108, perhaps, he do not considers whether bilinear form is symmetric/skew-symmetric etc; he just consider's *non-singular*.

**Question 2.** If a bilinear space $V$ is symmetric or skew symmetric over a field of characteristic $\neq 2$, then is there always an isometry with determinant $-1$?

Comment: Aren't your questions already answered in the quote? There is no such element if the isomorphism group does not contain reflections. So are you asking for an example of such a non-singular space?

Comment: Sorry; my question could be very trivial as you are guessing. But my question in more simply whether the case of *no reflections* occurs only in characteristic 2?

Comment: Over finite fields, you always have reflections (even though they have determinant 1 in characteristic 2), so you would need to look for a counter-example over an infinite field. Unfortunately, the theory over infinite fields is not complete yet. A search for "orthogonal group contains reflections" might help you a little, if there is a counter-example known you might find it.